# Infinite Loop after Genesis Theme Upgrade

Tags: loop, themes, redirect, upgrade

I'm running WordPress on Microsoft Azure, and I've been having a lot of timeout errors any time I try to install or update plugins/themes. (I'm using a custom child theme, based on Genesis.) Today, I tried to use the update screen in the admin area to update the Genesis theme to the latest version. The upgrade timed out, and when I tried to go back to /wp-admin it redirected me to **/wp-admin/admin.php?page=genesis&upgraded=true**, I am getting an error screen showing "**This webpage has a redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**".

I can till access the public side of my site, but I cannot access the admin area at all, even if I try to go directly to a specific page like /wp-admin/themes.php or /wp-admin/widgets.php, it always redirects me to /wp-admin/admin.php?page=genesis&upgraded=true

I tried FTPing in and deleting and re-uploading the newest version of Genesis, but again, I get the same redirect.

Is there anything else I could try via the database or FTP to resolve this issue?

Comment: Seems like you messed up your server config. Try deactivating all plugins and switch to the default theme (rename or remove theme and plugins folders via sftp). If that does not solve it, then it's the server config. If deleting/renaming those directories does solve it, then it's some piece of code. Rename only one at a time, retry after each plugin/theme again to see if that solves it. Then edit your question and show your progress.

Comment: is this problem is solve? I am also getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the folder that contains the Genesis theme and you will be able to log into your site.

Also - before restoring your theme change your permalinks to standard. That will rewrite your .htaccess file to make sure it works with WordPress.

Then, once you reinstall Genesis, you should be able to restore your permalinks back to however you had them set.

Comment: It actually does - if amglori does this, he will be able to log into the website as admin because the redirect will disappear. PS - I edited the answer to also deal with potential .htaccess problems.